# Having Issue on Using each() With Multiple Input Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to use the `each` iterator to check empty inputs?

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            $(this).addClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper">a</div>
<div class="lower">b</div>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<div class="upper">7</div>
<div class="lower">w</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<div class="upper">o</div>
<div class="lower">66</div>
<input type="text" id="txt3"><br />
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Use `$(this).addClass('error');`

Comment: THanks Tushar but it was just a typo mistake and as you can see still not working

Comment: `if($(this).val().length === 0) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").each(function(i,v){
       console.log($(v).val().length)
        if($(v).val().length == 0){
         
            $(v).addClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error{border-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper">a</div>
<div class="lower">b</div>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<div class="upper">7</div>
<div class="lower">w</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<div class="upper">o</div>
<div class="lower">66</div>
<input type="text" id="txt3"><br />
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements at `html` at Question do not have `value` attribute to return `.length` of ?

Try setting `value` attribute at `input` elements to retrieve `$(this).val()` or `this.value` within `.each()` ; substituting `.toggelClass()` for `.addClass()` to toggle `"error"` `class` at `#test` element `click` event if `input` `.length` changes

```js
$("#test").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("input").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("error", !this.value.length);
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="upper">a</div>
<div class="lower">b</div>
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="">
<div class="upper">7</div>
<div class="lower">w</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2" value="1">
<div class="upper">o</div>
<div class="lower">66</div>
<input type="text" id="txt3" value="">
<br />
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have no problem with your code, everything is running.
if i fill something into the inputs then it is running into the if-clause.

but what you want to do with "error"? since version 1.8 it is deprecated and
in your coding there is no error-handler, you give a string as parameter to error not a handler (function). 
read : https://api.jquery.com/error/

in your case it is better to give the parent-element to the each function like:

```
$("input","body").each(
```

if you want to work with error, then:

```
$('#myelement').on('error',function(){ /*your error code */});
```

for your example it is not the right way to bind the error handler on your input-element, if you want to check the values of the inputs. the error-handler catch thinks like "undefined" but it is not a system-error if your inputs are empty.

try:

```
if($(this).val().length > 0){
    console.log('Input Val has ' + this).val().length + ' characters')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, you want the empty input fields to be highlighted once you click the "Test" button, while the one's with values should not be highlighted. If so, then please check this solution:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).addClass('error');
        }else{
          $(this).removeClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper">a</div>
<div class="lower">b</div>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<div class="upper">7</div>
<div class="lower">w</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<div class="upper">o</div>
<div class="lower">66</div>
<input type="text" id="txt3"><br />
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```